# How to draw a line with arrow using touch in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, draw

I was looking to draw a line which contains an arrow mark.How to show it with arrow on head is a problem.Is it possible to do without line renderer?

Attaching a link here to show the drawing of line on screen.[Draw Arrow](https://thumbs.gfycat.com/DisgustingAgitatedIvorybilledwoodpecker-mobile.mp4).If I swipe to the right the arrow head points to right with hand held on screen I can change my position of arrow head.Once I release the arrow position is fixed.

I have worked out to draw a line between two points.Code given below.

```
if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {


        //--Clearing the list and adding first touch to list--
        fingerPositions.Clear();
        fingerPositions.Add(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        Debug.Log("Made first touch");
        click = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        isSwiping = true;


    }

    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended && isSwiping == true)
    {
        //--Adding the last touch to the list--
        fingerPositions.Add(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        //currenline is GameObject
        currenline = Instantiate(linePrefab, fingerPositions[0], Quaternion.identity);
        getAllLines.Add(currenline);
        //NewLine is a LineRenderer
        NewLine = currenline.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        Debug.Log("Finger count = "+fingerPositions.Count);

        NewLine.SetPosition(0, fingerPositions[0]);
        NewLine.SetPosition(1, fingerPositions[1]);




        isSwiping = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In you line prefab add a triangle sprite which is anchored to the end edge of the prefab. If it's a child it'll keep it's orientation so you just have to create the line and arrow will follow.

Comment: I created a canvas image and added as child of LineRenderer ..but when instantiated arrow keeps the orientation when I initially set . It doesnt change the orientation.

Comment: @zyonneo I thought you had a prefab with arrow head. Anyways, you can do this by calculating [angle between](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.SignedAngle.html) the arrow vector and the direction of the arrow head sprite. You can then update the arrow's local rotation (euler angles) to that value on the correct axis.

Comment: I am using Line renderer to draw lines.

Comment: @zyonneo yeah. the above solution should work. give it a shot.

Comment: any examples...Could only draw lines with line renderer